# Make WordPress User Name the Email Address When Register

Tags: login, wp-login-form

Is it possible to make WordPress user name the Email Address? when user register in my site.

So unername could be hidden or not required and is replaced with email address.

I use [WP User Frontend](http://docs.wedevs.com/category/plugins/wp-user-frontend-pro/) plugin.

I know there are plugins that can allow users to use their email as the log in, but they still have to enter the username when they register. I want to try and do away with the username.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `user_register`-hook, to replace the username with the mail-address right after the account has been created.

It could be something like this (untested) in your `functions.php`:

```
add_action( 'user_register', 'wpse216787_mail_as_username', 10, 1 );

function wpse216787_mail_as_username( $user_id ) {
    $email = get_the_author_meta( 'user_email', $user_id );
    update_user_meta($user_id, 'user_login', $email );
}
```

Comment: Hi @flomei ,, Sory its not work , its not set username like email

Comment: Any error messages?

Comment: i test to register in my site and go to phpmyadmin to show user_login, its not like user_email

Comment: and i try to login with email, but its say the username not correct

Comment: Well, then debug the code and check where the problem is.

Comment: the error is the table of user not update

Comment: That´s obvious, try to get my code to work, it was just a little push in a possible direction.